# How to remove an string from a array using the includes and splice method?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove  specific element from a array in javascript, but, when I use the splice method, it deletes the whole array, instead of the specific element.

Code:

```js
const cart = {
  contents: [],
  
  addItem(item) {
    cart.contents.push(item);
  },

  removeItem(item) {
    let searchItem = this.contents;

    if (searchItem.includes(item, 0)) {
      searchItem.splice(item);
      console.log(`${item} successfully removed from cart`);
    } else {
      console.log(`You tried to remove ${item} from your cart, but ${item} is not in the cart`);
    };
  }
};

cart.addItem("laptop");
cart.addItem("pen");
cart.addItem("book");

console.log("The cart contains:", cart.contents);
cart.removeItem("laptop");
console.log("The cart contains:", cart.contents);
```

the console log:

```
"The cart contains:" ["laptop", "pen", "book"] <br>
"laptop successfully removed from cart" <br>
"The cart contains:" []
```

Comment: update it to `searchItem.splice(item,1);`

Comment: By default it splices to the end of the array. You have to specify the length if you want it to remove fewer.

Comment: `item` is a string. `splice` takes an index of the array as an argument. Not the element itself. You need to get the index first and then `splice`

Comment: @Aalexander `item` is the string OP is trying to remove

Comment: If you pass a non-number to `splice`, it will remove every item from the array. Weird.

Comment: thanks @adiga. I was able to fix by finding the index of the array as you said.

```
removeItem(item) {
   
  let searchItem = this.contents;
   
   if (searchItem.includes(item,0) ) {
    var a = searchItem.indexOf(item);
     searchItem.splice(1,a);
    
     console.log(`${item} successfully removed from cart` );
     
   } else {
     console.log(`You tried to remove ${item} from your cart, but ${item} is not in the cart`);
   };
  }
```

Comment: The order of arguments to `splice` is wrong. It should be `searchItem.splice(a,1)`  <-- `a` is the index to remove. `1` is the number of items to remove starting from that index. Also, you  don't need the second argument to includes. By default, it will start from 0. So, `searchItem.includes(item)` is enough

Comment: Oh yes, you absolute right, I fixed, the order was wrong. Thanks for the tip on the includes.

Comment: Also, you don't need to search the array twice with `includes` and `indexOf`. Just get the index outside the if condition: `let index = searchItem.indexOf(item); if(index > -1) { // splice } else { // you tried to remove but doesn't exist}`

Comment: @adiga true instead of item it has to be the position of the element you like to remove